# How to capture the JavaScript that is executed on the page and print it into the log with Cordova InAppBrowser？

Tags: javascript, cordova, capture, execute, inappbrowser

We using the Angular5.2.9 + Ionic3.2 + Ionic Native 4.5.3 + Cordova8.0 to make an iOS app with a Cordova InAppBrowser to access some Pages.

We want to capture all the JavaScript that's been executed on the page and print it to the log.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Please help us. Thank you very much.

Comment: what does "capture all the Javascript" mean?

Comment: I am sorry. What I'm trying to say is  “intercept all the Javascript that's been executed on the page ”.